# PostgreSQL Error: My function returns Empty

Tags: sql, postgresql

EDIT!

I modified my function to this one

```
create or replace function get_by_distance(userlocation point)
returns table (name text, category text, subcategory text, department text, geolocation point, distance float)
as $BODY$
begin
return query
select listings."name", listings."category", listings."subcategory", listings."department", listings."geoloctaion", (userlocation <@> geoloctaion) as distance
from listings
where distance < 20
order by (userlocation <@> geoloctaion);
end;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

And now I'm getting an empty return, it compiles and I can call it but I'm getting nothing from the editor. And I'm also trying to call it using an external api and I'm getting this error:
`Could not find the public.functionName() function in the schema cache`
But I don't get that error with other simple functions.

Summarizing:
The function returns empty inside editor (while the actual select with same data returns the rows).
The function returns an error when trying to call it from outside editor.

Comment: Your table definition doesn’t include the distance column

Comment: Do you get the error when you create the function, or when you invoke it?  If the latter, then you need to show us that.

Comment: I modified the function and now it returns nothing (empty). I posted it below

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line

```
(userlocation <@> geoloctaion)::point as distance
```

Is causing the problem.
The documentation says that the function returns a float

```
point <@> point → float8
```

We could avoid the error by removing the cast `::point`

```
(userlocation <@> geolocation as distance
```

Comment: I modified the function and now it returns nothing (empty). I posted it below

Answer (score 0):

I modified the function and now it returns nothing (empty).
I can compile it and I can call it but it returns empty...

When I run the select only it returns me the Rows so there's a problem with the function itself.

Here's the snippet of the new try:

```
create or replace function get_by_distance(userlocation point)
returns table (name text, category text, subcategory text, department text, geolocation point, distance float)
as $BODY$
begin
return query
select listings."name", listings."category", listings."subcategory", listings."department", listings."geoloctaion", (userlocation <@> geoloctaion) as distance
from listings
where distance < 20
order by (userlocation <@> geoloctaion);
end;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Try removing the where clause to see what is returned. It may be that you need to write in full `WHERE (userlocation <@> geolocation) < 20`

Comment: Two possible issues 1) the first line in the body is a return statement so the SP will return at that point and never run the query 2) SPs are not used for returning values, if you want to return  table that you can subsequently query then you need to use a function not a SP

Comment: Yes I solved it yesterday, as you said it was the were 